# iOS loading executable from a bundle

Tags: ios, dynamic, loading, nsbundle

According to the documentation for [NSBundle load] method :

**Dynamically loads the bundle’s executable code into a running program, if the code has not already been loaded.**

I have tried this in an iOS project and it works perfectly, my question is if i upload this to App Store, is this a reason for rejection? I read that dynamically loading libraries (dylib) causes Apple to reject your app but i think am not using a dynamic library just an innocent bundle :), anybody tried this approach and distributed to App Store?

Regards,

Can

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this only works when XCode debugger attached, otherwise application is terminated immediately  **Exited: Killed: 9**.